# ASP.NET Core could not find views

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core application.
The application needs to be started by windows service. When the service runs the application, I'm having the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The following locations were searched:
 /Views/Home/Index.cshtml
 /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
EnsureSuccessful
MoveNext
ThrowForNonSuccess
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
MoveNext
ThrowForNonSuccess
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
MoveNext
MoveNext
ThrowForNonSuccess
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
MoveNext
MoveNext
ThrowForNonSuccess
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
MoveNext
ThrowForNonSuccess
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
MoveNext
ThrowForNonSuccess
HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification
MoveNext
```

However, if I run the application by clicking on the exe-file, everything seems to be normal.
I double checked, the service had enough permissions, and the views are in the right place.

BUT! I had a situation when the service was looking for another file somewhere in win32 folder, because I had made a mistake and used `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` instead of `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` to find the current folder. Is it possible that the similar mistake had been made?

Comment: Try to set current directory on service start up. The default is  System32 I think

Comment: @ Aleksey L. Thanks, I just figured it out! :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The current problem was indeed similar to the former. As it turned out, I should have used the same `Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)` in Startup.cs:Main

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseConfiguration(config)
    .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location))
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .Build();
```

where by default `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` was used as an argument for `UseContentRoot(.)`. Also the same operation must be performed several lines of code earlier, when `ConfigurationBuilder` is called.

The root of the problem is that the windows service is being called from win32 folder, so `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` is giving win32 folder instead of folder of executable file.